# torch.cuda.is_available() returns false in colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use GPU in google colab. Below are the details of the versions of pytorch and cuda installed in my colab.

```
Torch 1.3.1 CUDA 10.1.243

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

I am pretty new to using a GPU for transfer learning on pytorch models. My torch.cuda.is_available() returns false and I am unabel to use a GPU. torch.backends.cudnn.enabled returns true. What might be going wrong here?

Comment: you also need to make sure your colab instance actually has a GPU in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with all the versions mentioned above and I did not have to downgrade my CUDA to 10.0. I had restarted my colab after the updates which set my running machine back to CPU and I just had to change it back to GPU.

Answer (score 21):

Make sure your Hardware accelerator is set to GPU.

`Runtime > Change runtime type > Hardware Accelerator`

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else comes here and makes the same mistake I was making:

If you are trying to check if GPU is available and you do:

```
if torch.cuda.is_available:
  print('GPU available')
else:
  print('Please set GPU via Edit -> Notebook Settings.')
```

It will always seem that GPU is available. Note you need to use `torch.cuda.is_available()` not `torch.cuda.is_available`.

Answer (score 1):

(This worked in Jan 2021)

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cu101 torchvision==0.6.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

with my params:

```
!nvcc --version
# nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
# Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
# Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
# Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporal fix may be to try Cuda 10.0 as [explained in here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/28321).

Something like this:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

In future versions this may work.

Answer (score 0):

When I install torchvision, GPU became available

```
!pip install torchvision
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
!pip install torch==1.11.0+cu102 torchvision==0.12.0+cu102 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I noticed that installing torch with `+cuXXX` (XXX are numbers) would work. Try `!pip list` before installing torch and you'd see the version of torch which is running on Colab. It has `+cuXXX`. I think these versions would use the GPUs.

Please tell me if I get it wrong.